# Deploying Python bottle app with pymssql on heroku

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, freetds, pymssql

I'm having issues with deploying my website with pymssql onto heroku.  I'm using the following build pack and still am having errors:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/amanjain/heroku-buildpack-python-freetds-pymssql.git
```

This is the error that I keep getting:

```
remote:            warning: no files found matching 'pymssql_version.py'
remote:            warning: no files found matching 'win32/freetds.zip'
remote:            warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
remote:        Successfully installed pymssql
remote:        Cleaning up...
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Downloading/unpacking bottle==0.12.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u13919/bottle/setup.py) egg_info for package bottle
remote:            
remote:        Downloading/unpacking DateTime==4.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u13919/DateTime/setup.py) egg_info for package DateTime
remote:            
remote:        Downloading/unpacking functools32==3.2.3.post2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement functools32==3.2.3.post2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: 3.2.3-1, 3.2.3-1, 3.2.3-2, 3.2.3-2)
remote:        Cleaning up...
remote:        No distributions matching the version for functools32==3.2.3.post2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:        Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python + FreeTDS + pymssql app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to shelf2xerotest1.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shelf2xerotest1.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to     
'https://git.heroku.com/shelf2xerotest1.git'
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I haven't found a way to deploy pymssql to heroku - due to missing C libraries. If you do, please post an answer. It may be required to add a check to the python buildpack, as they do for cffi (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/cryptography)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that buildpack is built for Linux systems, and it appears you're trying to install it on Windows.

In the trace log, it appears to be looking for a FreeTDS build in a win32 directory:

```
warning: no files found matching 'win32/freetds.zip'
```

It also appears to be install Python 2.7. If you're just getting started, I'd strongly recommend using Python 3. Good luck.

Comment: Windows? what?! It's Heroku! Python 3? This answer makes no sense.

Comment: That's exactly what I was pointing out from the output! It doesn't make sense. Why's it looking for a win32 library? Why the Python-2.7 tag in the question?

Comment: It's not a win32 compilation error, its saying theres no file called 'win32/freetds.zip'. Nothing to do with running on windows. All the paths in the log are Unix paths. Python 2.7 works with no issues, please don't blanket "answer" by advocating python 3, it's lazy.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's hardly advocating for Python 3; 2 has an EOL and if anyone is getting started and choosing, 3 is the way to go. Wall of Shame -> Superpowers!